# Listing all the existing VPCs of an account via AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Wondering if there's a way with the AWS CDK to **list all the available VPCs** for the current account.

For example the CLI provides `aws ec2 describe-vpcs` which is very handy to retrieve all the available VPCs.

I can also import a VPC if I know its identifier (python example) :

```py
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc", vpc_id=vpc_id)
```

However at this point, I haven't found a way to retrieve all (or filtered) VPCs (or their ids) using the CDK. Any pointers ?

Note : we're currently passing a CIDR block string to the `cdk` command line so we can configure the `cidr` parameter of the `aw2s_ec2.Vpc` [constructor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Vpc.html#vpc). We would like to avoid that and let the application find the next available CIDR block on its own (or the one that was used for this deployment if previously created). For example, [`Vpc.private_subnets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Vpc.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Vpc.private_subnets) offers a way to list all private subnets (and their CIDR blocks) for an existing vpc, so I would have assumed the same could be obtained for vpcs in an AWS account.

Comment: What do you want to do with that list of VPCs once you got it?

Comment: @aax - Edited my question to provide a little bit of background. Let me know if the intent is any clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: don't.

Long answer: This is against AWS CDK best practices. As described in the [docs on the topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/best-practices.html), CDK apps should be deterministic. That is, CDK code (along with context) in your VCS should always synth to the same template:

> Determinism is key to successful AWS CDK deployments. A AWS CDK app
> should have essentially the same result whenever it is deployed
> (notwithstanding necessary differences based on the environment where
> it's deployed).

Using AWS SDK in your CDK code breaks this determinism, so it's a good idea to rethink your approach.

Comment: Fair point.  It's pretty straightforward to make that a CDK Parameter, and use the same boto3 code as a pre-processor to pass it in.

Comment: I am not sure I am suggesting to mix theSDK and CDK code. I was merely giving an example that showed the SDK could retrieve the list of VPCs. I would like to avoid passing a CIDR block when my stack creates a new VPC -- currently passing a string as cmd line parameter to use as  the CIDR block of the VPC (see my edit)

Comment: From the best practice link you mentioned above, it states : "For example, a common CDK idiom, iterating over a list and instantiating a construct with values from each item in the list, simply isn't possible using AWS CloudFormation expressions." This is very similar to what I'd like to accomplish by asking the CDK for a list of available VPCs and their respective CIDR block string. Would that not be acceptable ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, your CDK code should always synth to the same template, no matter where it's deployed. CDK apps should be deterministic.

Comment: I think it should be considered as general "Infrastructure as Code" best practices.  They want version X of the template to have the same behavior every time.

Functionally, there's no difference between dynamically determining the subnet and passing that in as a Parameter, and having CDK determining the subnet for you.  It will work, or it won't.  The difference is, in my opinion, a bit of semantics.  Fundamentally, you aren't _quite_ doing Infrastructure as Code as typically described, but if your environment is static, it should be reliable.

Comment: If the environment were static, there would be no need to do the lookup - you could just hardcode it.

Comment: Having the CDK code be deterministic makes since, when feasible. But what if you have existing infrastructure in AWS and want to start using CDK going forward? Is there some way to bootstrap stack definitions that match your current infrastructure, similar to [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer)?

Answer (score 2):

The great thing about CDK, in my opinion, is the pre-processing you can do on your templates.  I have done similar things by combining `boto3` in my CDK code.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    core as cdk,
    aws_ec2 as ec2
)

import boto3

class CdkTestStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here
        client = boto3.client('ec2')
        all_vpcs = client.describe_vpcs()
        
        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "vpc", vpc_id=all_vpcs['Vpcs'][2]['VpcId'])
        sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, 'testSG',
                               vpc=vpc)
        sg.add_ingress_rule(peer=ec2.Peer.any_ipv4(),
                            connection=ec2.Port.tcp(80))
```

Running `cdk synth`, we get:

```
Resources:
  testSG462E14A9:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: CdkTestStack/testSG
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Allow all outbound traffic by default
          IpProtocol: "-1"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: from 0.0.0.0/0:80
          FromPort: 80
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 80
      VpcId: vpc-1234567890abcdefg
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: CdkTestStack/testSG/Resource
  CDKMetadata:
:
```

Comment: This would lead to a non-deterministic CDK app, which is advised against.